# Angular CLI 6.0.1 how to control dev environment and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli-v6

This is part of **angular.json**:

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

What I want to do is to control the **development environment**. For example change `sourceMap` to `false` and I do not want to do that by adding parameters to `ng build`. *Is there any equivalent to `production` inside `angular.json` which will refer to development*?

And something very **important**: In Angular-CLI 6 there is no `ng eject`! How then, is it possible to see and modify **webpack.config.js** ?

Comment: Why was this downvoted without any comments? This is a good questions because the Angular CLI docs does not specify anything on how to control the `development` build config. The two options in the accepted answer are valid.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really do not understand why some guys downvote  a question while not being able to answer that!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default settings for all environments are configured in the `architect > build > options` property

```
 "projects": {
    "MyProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",

            //Add settings here
            "sourceMap": false,
             "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.anotherdevenv.ts"
                }
            ]
```

These settings are used as is for the dev env, so you can modify this (but this will impact other environments if they do not override the specified setting)

You can also create your own "development" configuration (by copying the production conf for instance, and changing depending en your needs), and specify in that conf your setting specific to the dev environment. Then run the command below

```
ng serve -c development
```

The `eject` command is temporarily disabled, but it should be added back soon according to a comment by a core member of angular cli team (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10945)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. By the way, do you have any idea why angular-cli creates source map files for  some files I have inside my project? Not for components, services etc. but for some .ts files which create models and constants....

Comment: I'd assume it creates source map for every single ts file

Answer (score 0):

I found webpack config here: node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.js